# Why does my regex work on client and fail on server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I am using a regex that is supposed to validate a username. A username should include only an English letter, number or underscore.
Client - side code input works as expected and not allowing anything except for letters, numbers, and undescore:

```
              <input
                type="text"
                name="username"
                id="username"
                required
                minlength="2"
                maxlength="14"
                pattern="[A-Za-z0-9_]+"
                class="form__input"
              />
```

When I try to submit a username that includes `!`, browser validation doesn't allow it to happen.

Now, on my server-side (Express app + Yup) I use the same regex, however, it's not working as expected:

```
    const shema = yup.object().shape({
  username: yup
    .string()
    .required()
    .trim()
    .min(2)
    .max(14)
    .matches(/[A-Za-z0-9_]+/, 'Only English letters, numbers, and underscore allowed (2-14 characters)')})
```

When I use Postman and send a post request with a username than includes `!`, validation does not work.
All other fields validate as expected, therefore, it's probably some problem with my regex ? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In HTML, a pattern attribute implicitly spans the *whole length* of the input value - it's as if it has invisible `^` and `$`s at each end. For example:

```html
<form>
  <button>submit will fail because more than one digit exists in the input</button>
  <input pattern="\d" value="123">
</form>
```

To make your pattern on the server carry out the same logic that's being done on the client, use:

```
.matches(/^[A-Za-z0-9_]+$/
```

Or, even better, use `\w`, which matches alphabetical, numerical, and `_` characters:

```
.matches(/^\w+$/
```

You can do this on the client as well:

```html
<form>
  <button>submit</button>
  <input pattern="\w+">
</form>
```

Comment: yeah that fixed my issue. Thank you! I'll accept when 15 minutes are up.